# How to exclude folders from search except a few?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work on a large project with many files. I want to exclude as many files as possible.

I want to exclude `**/node_modules`, but except a few that are created by my company. e.g. `**/node_modules/@mycomp`.

Is it possible today in vscode 1.8.1?

Thanks,

Unional

Comment: I assume you tried adding them to the settings.json search.exclude list?  It probably won't take a negation ! glob indicator though.

Comment: Yes, I am. Maybe a FR?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to only show the `node_modules/swagger-tools` folder.

In the `.vscode/settings.json` file I wrote the following rules:

1. Filter all folders starting with the dot character or every letter except **s**.
2. Filter all folders starting with **s** and is followed by every letter except **w**.
3. Filter every folder starting with **swagger-** (at this point all the remaining folders started with **swagger-**) and is followed by every letter except **t**.

So the file ended up like this:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
      "node_modules/[abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz.]*": true,
      "node_modules/s[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz]*": true,
      "node_modules/swagger-[abcdefghijklmnopqrsuvwxyz]*": true,
    }
}
```

Arguably is not the nicest thing to do but certainly does the trick.